# Alternative location for chkmatch?

Tags: debugging, portable-executable, pdb-files

I am trying to find a copy of the program chkmatch.  The link everyone points to is http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html, however this site seem to no longer be up.  Does anyone know of a mirror or alternate download location or even an alternative program?  I am trying to make a PDB and dll match for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There's Wayback Machine website that helps in such situations

https://web.archive.org/web/20210205095232/https://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html

(And I assume you understand that the DLL and the PDB should be built from the same source with the same options, otherwise it is useless and may give misleading information)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier with no luck.  Not sure what the deal was, but it does seem to be working now.